# Merge the various retrocomputing tags

Tags: discussion, status-declined, retag-request

[retro](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/retro) 8 questions
[legacy](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/legacy) 25 questions
[vintage](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/vintage) 24 questions

I would suggest for these a common tag [retrocomputing](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/retrocomputing).

Comment: there are a few items in legacy that are not retro. Bios legacy support might refer to backwards compatability, but USB is not exactally retro yet :-)

Comment: I agree with Psycogeek. See: [Legacy system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system). Vintage and retro, however, usually imply the same thing.

Comment: @Psycogeek What’s compatability?

Comment: @Psycogeek Also, it means „USB support for legacy O/S” (such as MS-DOS)

Comment: @kinokijuf compatibility.  Whatever, I was just saying that there are a few things in there that do not apply, that is all. http://superuser.com/questions/303365/what-does-legacy-usb-mouse-support-in-a-bios-mean , http://superuser.com/questions/277893/how-can-i-remedy-a-conflict-between-a-usb-disk-and-usb-legacy-support-in-the-bio

Answer (score 1):

This is [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined) - each of these tags has a different meaning and connotation - as discussed in the comments, that don't all mean the same thing, so it is too confusing and complicated to remap them to [retrocomputing](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/retrocomputing).